# How does outbound email handle recipient data in SDL Tridion 2013?

Tags: 2013, templating, outbound-email, external-integrations

I am considering Outbound Email for a requirement I need to fullfil, which is, replace recipient data from an external source when emails are sent. 
So, when emails are rendered, do my templates have access to all the contact details? If I add another Template Building Block, would I have the ability for example to read the Client ID?

I need execute further logic depending on the contact information, for example, I know that some place holders can be replaced automatically, like name, last name, etc...
but what I need to do here is link urls replacement in links and even full component presentations need to be swapped depending on "who" is receiving the email.

As you can tell, I am not very familiar with OE (Outbound Email), so any directions will help.

**Note:** Target Groups are not really an option, since we have 1K+ different "target groups" and I don't want to add 1k+ headers, 1k+ footers, etc...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I believe this is pretty straight forward (haven't used it before other than name/email). You can use any Contact Extended Details fields in your templates. [* ContactDetail *]

Check the documentation [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=CompoundTemplating_MergeFields.xml&docid=concept_GDGD657775B5C4E1AB6D8E852ADF6502D&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_GDGD657775B5C4E1AB6D8E852ADF6502D) for further information.

Comment: Do keep in mind that the template is only rendered once for all of the Contacts, when you Test the Mailing. The replacement of Contact details happens later (when the Mailer Service actually generates each individual e-mail). So depending on what you actually need to do, you may need to employ some workarounds (I can help with suggestions there)